# No privileges in phpmyadmin; tried root with no password

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have PHP 5.2 and MySQL5 up and running on a virtual machine and am trying to create a database using phpmyadmin. While I can login successfully with a username and password I chose before, I have no permissions to create databases. I tried logging in as root with no password, and when that didn't work I changed the config.inc.php file like so:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

It still doesn't work...

How do I grant myself privileges so I can create a database already??

Comment: Is root@localhost set to create databases?

Comment: if you can use the command line/shell, enter the mysql console by running `mysql -u root -p` ; once inside, you should run the code `grant all on *.* to root;`. Then, run `flush privileges;` for the database to reload the privileges.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running on Windows 7. When I go to the directory phpmyadmin is in and try to type the 'mysql' command it says it's not recognized. @Machavity: not sure if it is as I can't login on root and logging in under my current name won't allow me to set privileges.

Comment: Are you using a WAMP-style stack or individually installed components?

Comment: I made a puphpet file using Puphpet Labs, installed Vagrant and VirtualBox, and got everything up and running that way. Then I installed phpmyadmin in the localhost directory. So far everything's working (as in I can view web pages I've made at the localhost:8080 address). I just can't make databases to make my sites functional!

Answer (score 0):

if you are the admin of the system then back to login and go to the mysql setting in phpmyadmin, and then go to privileges tab and set the privileges for the login name through which you can login,
by the way this type of error would be remove simply..

check your connection..

$con='localhost','username','password';
the above connection is used for authorized user and the below is for every one..

$con='localhost','root',;

hope will help you.. ;)

Comment: I guess I don't have the privilege to set my own privileges...if that makes sense. Tried this and it didn't work.

Where would I put those $con commands? In the phpmyadmin configuration file? Command line under the directory containing phpmyadmin?

Comment: dear! install the xammp or wammp, it contain all the php,mysql,filezillah etc... iam currently using the xammp latest version and it is working fine, you can also try it, may be you will find it easier...

Answer (score 0):

Ok everyone. Turns out I had to go under:

```
pupppet/hieradata/common.yaml
```

and find my root password (which I apparently set up while making the Puphpet file). Once I got that I was able to login and give myself privileges. *sigh*

Thank you all for your responses :)